# Differentiation on manifold, second derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F$ be smooth function on manifold and $v$ vector field. Set

$$G(x) := dF_x(v(x)).$$

If $w$ is another vector field, how do I work out $dG_x(w(x))$? I guess should be

$$dG_x(w(x)) = d^2F_x(v(x),w(x)),$$

but am not sure how to make formalism work (how define $d^2F$?)

Comment: The derivative of $G$ will involve the derivatives of $v$, thus it cannot be the expression you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about $G$ as a composition of maps between manifolds
$$ M \mathop{\to}_v TM \mathop{\to}_{dF} \Bbb R,$$
then you can just apply the chain rule to get $D_xG(w) = D_vdF(D_x v(w))$ where the derivatives are taken in higher tangent bundles:

$$ TM \mathop{\to}_{Dv} TTM \mathop{\to}_{DdF} \Bbb R.$$

In coordinates you can expand this using partial derivatives to $DG(w) = w^i v^j F_{,ij} + w^i F_{,j} v^j_{,i}$; so *if you have a Riemannian structure* you get a coordinate-free formula something like what you were looking for:

$$ DG(w) = \nabla^2 F(v,w) + dF( \nabla_w v ).$$

Here $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection and $\nabla^2$ the covariant Hessian.